# JSON Array - select from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, select

I've got example array:

```
{
 "orders": [
   {
     "order_id": 1,
     "email": "alex@alex.com",
     "city": "London"
   },
   {
     "order_id": 2,
     "email": "tom@tom.com",
     "city": "Miami"
   }
 ]
}
```

and variable `var email = "tom@tom.com"`.
I have to `select order_id and city from array where email = "tom@tom.com"`
Have you got any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

By using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const data = { "orders": [{ "order_id": 1, "email": "alex@alex.com", "city": "London" }, { "order_id": 2, "email": "tom@tom.com", "city": "Miami" }] };

const result = data.orders.filter(({email}) => email === 'tom@tom.com')
                          .map(({order_id, city}) => ({ order_id, city }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
let json = { 
"orders": [
   {
     "order_id": 1,
     "email": "alex@alex.com",
     "city": "London"
   },
   {
     "order_id": 2,
     "email": "tom@tom.com",
     "city": "Miami"
   }
 ]
}
var email = "tom@tom.com"
json['orders'].map(function(item){
if (item.email == email){
  console.log(item.order_id);
  console.log(item.city);
}
});
```